# web services call from a web application running on tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat

When trying to make a web service (hosted on a different server) call from a web application running on Apache Tomcat 5.5.23 we are getting the below listed error.

The certificates are imported to the JKS and the web service call is successfully made as part the unit testing.

Appreciate your help.

The error logs are

an error occured:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:98)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
 at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:542)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
 at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
 at custom.tibco.TibcoClientStub_PortType2.docRetrieval(TibcoClientStub_PortType2.java:210)
 at custom.tibco.TibcoArchiveHandler.loadImages(TibcoArchiveHandler.java:144)
 at de.softpro.signplus.thinclient.signcheck.SCWorkspaceProxy.loadAlternateArchiveImages(SCWorkspaceProxy.java:1067)
 at de.softpro.signplus.thinclient.signcheck.SCWorkspaceProxy.getSpecificArchiveDocument(SCWorkspaceProxy.java:872)
 at de.softpro.signplus.thinclient.signcheck.GetSpecificAction.execute(GetSpecificAction.java:136)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at de.softpro.signplus.thinclient.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at de.softpro.signplus.thinclient.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:58)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
 at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
 at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:150)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1584)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:174)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:168)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:848)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:106)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:877)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1089)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
 at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:80)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:89)
 ... 48 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:221)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:145)
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:203)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:172)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:320)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:841)
 ... 59 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:236)
 at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:194)
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:216)
 ... 64 more
```

Comment: u haven't accepted any questions in the last 6 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using HTTPS and do not have a valid KeyStore configured.